# How to use gdata classes to search youtube videos

Tags: ios4, youtube-api, gdata-api

hi all 
i am making an app which uses gdata apis . i have included gdata apis in my app but know i dont know how to use the gdata framework to search all the videos with a search query . i want the i output in the form which has a thumbnail in the tableview and a title and description of video.

I'm really frustrated  and search a lot on google but no right solution is there.

Please help me guys

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I didn't give up, and found the answer of how to use gdata framework.

http://www.iphonedevx.com/?p=126